# Don't allow 25Tan() but allow Tan(25)

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm making a calculator and I don't want the calculator to make the calculation if I have 25tan(), it should give a output 'Syntax Error', tan(25) on the other hand should work. I cna't make it work.

```
if(equation)
        {
            if(tan == true)
            {
                if(input.innerHTML = inputVal + 'Tan(')
                {
                    input.innerHTML = 'Syntax Error';
                    tan = false;    
                }               
                else
                {
                    inputVal = inputVal.replace('Tan(', '');
                    inputVal = inputVal.replace(')', '');
                    input.innerHTML = Math.tan(inputVal);
                }
            }
            input.innerHTML = eval(equation);
            //Om det är NaN så ersätts det med '0'
            if (isNaN(a))
            {
                a = 0;
            }
        }
```

I've edited this, but it gives me syntax error on both 25Tan() and Tan(25).

This is the fixed version

```
if(equation)
        {
            if(tan == true)
            {
                if(equation.indexOf('Tan(') == 0)
                {
                    inputVal = inputVal.replace('Tan(', '');
                    inputVal = inputVal.replace(')', '');
                    input.innerHTML = Math.tan(inputVal);
                }               
                else
                {           
                    input.innerHTML = 'Syntax Error';
                    tan = false;
                }
            }
            input.innerHTML = eval(equation);
            //Om det är NaN så ersätts det med '0'
            if (isNaN(a))
            {
                a = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the http://mathjs.org/ library? It may already do what you need, and avoid that nasty `eval` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want check if sub-string is contained in given string you should use indexOf function. It returns index of sub-string it the string. If sub-string is not present is the string function returns -1.

Then your code should looks like this:

```
if (equation) {
    if (tan == true) {
        if (input.value.indexOf('Tan(') == 0) {
            inputVal = input.value;
            inputVal = inputVal.replace('Tan(', '');
            inputVal = inputVal.replace(')', '');
            input.value = Math.tan(inputVal);
        } else {
            input.value = 'Syntax Error';
            tan = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        input.value = eval(equation);
    }
}
```

Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/suska/kUjf5/

Comment: I had to use my variable equation to get it work. `if(equation.IndexOf('Tan(') == 0)`